# Objective C - NSString - Memory basics

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to return an NSString that has been initialized from a plist.

If I comment out my release lines this code works. I would however like to release these objects from memory as I no longer need them.

I thought that 'initWithString' would copy the contents of the target string into my new string meaning I could safely release the NSMutableArray. But it isn't. Why not?

```
+ (NSString*) genImage {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"Images" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"%d", [arrayOfImages count]);

int indexToLoad = 0;

NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexToLoad] ];

[arrayOfImages release];
[path release];
return res;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not retain the return value of `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` (the `path` variable), so there is no need to release it (and doing so will cause a crash, most likely). However, you should autorelease `res`, as you *do* retain that. You can change your last line to

```
return [res autorelease];
```

Comment: right so because I didn't call 'alloc' on '*path' I should not release it. - Yes?

Comment: @andy boot: Basically. You can assume a method without `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` in the name returns an autoreleased object unless the documentation states otherwise (which is very rare).

Comment: I think you mean *retained* object (not autoreleased)!

Comment: @ipmcc: No, retained objects are generally only returned by methods with the word `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` in their name, unless the docs specify otherwise.

Comment: Ah... I see... I misparsed "without" as "with". Carry on!